# How to get iOS app Bundle ID that removed from app store and iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, bundle

I have deleted my **iOS application** from **iTunes connect** and **app store**. But forget Bundle ID that set on project.
Please tell me how to get this bundle id.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an IPA/code of the app? If you have an access, you can check for bundle ID for given name on Apple developer portal.

Comment: How did you delete the application from iTunesconnect ? Is there anyway to delete it from iTunesconnect ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your [developer](http://developer.apple.com/) account -> certificates & identifiers -> open the app id or provisioning profile certificates. Opening them displays your bundle identifier with which you have uploaded the app.